# Keyboard switching, multiple languages, define keyboard sequence for each

Tags: shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, language-support

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and have defined 4 languages. I am currently using <kbd>left alt</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd> to switch between them.

I would like though to define a specific key sequence for each one of the languages (in windows this is possible). For example, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> for English, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> for Spanish, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> for German, etc.

Anybody knows a way to do that?

Comment: Hey, I see you marked this question as duplicate, which is indeed. But this question was asked a few days BEFORE the other question was asked (and answered). So maybe the "This question has been asked before and already has an answer." is not exactly accurate :-)

Answer (score 3):

I do not think it is directly supported, but you can use the command line [`setxkbmap`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/setxkbmap.1.html) with the generic custom shortcut keys.

You have first of all to find the exact command that sets you keyboards; in my case I have

```
 setxkbmap es -variant standard_tlde
```

for the [my custom Spanish keyboard](http://rlog.rgtti.com/2014/05/01/how-to-modify-a-keyboard-layout-in-linux/) and

```
 setxkbmap us -variant altgr-intl
```

when I want the US-AltGr international one. The exact name of the variant is found in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/es` (or `us`, or `it` --- change as needed); for example, for the US variant I use, which is called "English (international AltGr dead keys)", it's here:

[image: excerpt of US xk symbols key]

When you have it, open Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcut Tab, go on Custom Shortcut, and add (with the `+`) the shortcuts:

[image: keyboard settings]

Type a name and the command you need. After that, you need to click on the "Disabled" word and type your shortcut:

[image: keyboard settings 2]

And you're set.

Notice though that keyboard layout switch is [plagued](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1289495) by [several](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1218322) and [important](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1246272) bugs, so you will have to use a lot of patience...

Answer (score 1):

Input sources on Ubuntu  can be set depending on the order they appear in the list. For instance, here is how my list of input sources look like.

[image]

The numbering starts at 0. This means that English is number 0 , Pinyin is number 1, and Russian is 2.

Knowing that, we can use `gsettings` command to set each source via it's number.

For instance, I could bind <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>1</kbd> to set English via command

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources current 0
```

For Pinyin, I could use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>2</kbd> and command

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources current 1
```

Hope you get the idea. Good luck !