# How to select language keyboard by hotkey?

Tags: shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

For example, press hotkey Ctrl+1 - select english, press Ctrl+2 - select other language etc. Any ideas?

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/a/688070/16395

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way unity/gnome change their language settings is through `gsettings` schema `org.gnome.desktop.input-sources`, and the key `current`. I've used it in several other scripts before to answer questions on Askubuntu.

Basic idea is that you run command

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources current $1
```

Where $1 is the number of the language source. Language sources are ordered starting from 0, just like shown in your drown down menu with all the languages. So suppose my language order is english, chinese, russian. English is source 0, chinese is source 1, russian is source 3.

So what can one do is go to System Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Custom. By clicking plus mark, create 3 shortcuts, for 3 numbers. I suggest you use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>number</kbd>, because <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>number</kbd> may be taken by an application, like firefox for it's own internal usage.

This I bind <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> to `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources current 0` for english. Repeat same process for chinese:  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> to `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources current 1`. Repeat the same for other sources

Comment: Ah, nice option. I used directly `setxkbmap` but this seems more elegant...  http://askubuntu.com/a/688070/16395

Comment: @Rmano `setxkbmap` works alright,too, especially with minimalistic desktops such as blackbox and openbox. I've used it couple of times and have no real complain about it. Out of the box it seems to lack chinese pinyin, which I think requires installing a package or compiling a keyboard layout.  The advantage of using `gsettings` is that it requires starting `gnome-settings-daemon` which means if  you have scripts linked to keyboard shortcuts set in Unity , they will be available in other desktops as well. And you can control tons of other utilities through gsettings,too