# ibus configuration - Selecting a language by one key

Tags: shortcut-keys, ibus, input-language

[image: fcitx_configuration]

This is the fcitx input method configuration.
I found the one key switch for a language is very useful than switch between two or multiple ones by <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> or <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.  I can type without thinking and ensure to hit the key before typing. This is very handy for a multi-lingual user.

Can we have this feature on to `ibus-setup`? I think I would do this by `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources current $1` but not easy to set this command to one shortcut key. There is no such option in Keyboard Shortcut settings.

I am afraid that beginners (like me) are not comfortable to set these by command line, and also they find Ubuntu useful and grateful if they could do this. I assume many of non-Latin language users who need to switch them very often are keen to have this.

ref:[How to select language keyboard by hotkey?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708549/how-to-select-language-keyboard-by-hotkey)

Answer (score 1):

Right, `ibus-setup` does not include an equivalent option. But with that said, some IBus engines do.

The `ibus-libpinyin` package, for instance, has a "Switch Chinese/English" option which you can control from the *Preferences -> Shortcuts* window.

(To test this, the package needs to be installed and the *Chinese (Intelligent Pinyin)* input method included in the list of input sources.)